# Problema con memoria dinámica

Tags: c, struct, memoria

Tengo estas 2 estructuras declaradas:

```
typedef struct {
    char *name;
    float quantity;
} tIngredient;

typedef struct {
    char *name;
    int id;
    float price;
    tIngredient *ingredients;
    int numIng;
} tBurguer;
```

Y luego en el main:

```
tBurguer b;
tIngredient i;

b.id = 0;
strcpy(b.name, "special");
b.ingredients=NULL;
b.numIng=0;
b.price=10.5;

strcpy(i.name, "lettuce");
i.quantity = 100;
add_ingredient (&b, i);
```

El código de add_ingredient() es el siguiente:

```
void add_ingredient (tBurguer *b, tIngredient i){
    
    if (strcmp(b->ingredients->name,i.name)!=0){
        b->numIng+=1;
        b->ingredients = (tIngredient*)realloc(b->ingredients, (b->numIng)*sizeof(tIngredient));
        strcpy (b->ingredients->name, i.name);
        b->ingredients->quantity = i.quantity;      
    } else {
        b->ingredients->quantity += i.quantity;
    }
}
```

Lo que intento hacer es comparar primero si el ingrediente que se encuentra en i.name es igual al que se encuentre en b.ingredients.name, para añadirlo si no existe o aumentar b.ingredients.quantity con lo que guarde i.quantity en caso de que ya exista. Y con el realloc quiero redimensionar el array manteniendo lo anterior para indicar que estamos añadiendo un nuevo ingrediente (en caso de que este no exista).

Mi duda es:

1. El malloc dónde se haría, ya que ese es el main que me dan, y no tengo posibilidad de añadir ni borrar cosas. Si lo hago en la función, me va como a dimensionar cada vez que la llame, pero no creo que eso es lo que deba hacer siempre.
2. Cómo podría acceder a un puntero a estructura dentro de otra. Creo que mi fallo viene por todo esto.

**CORRECCIÓN**
Hice lo siguiente gracias a la ayuda de los comentarios:

1. Los array de tipo char * de los structs los cambié a tamaño estático de 50, ya que interpreté mal el enunciado.
2. En la función, reservé la memoria de esta forma:

   void add_ingredient (tBurguer *b, tIngredient i){

   ```
    if (b->numIng==0){
        b->ingredients = (tIngredient*)malloc(b->numIng*sizeof(tIngredient));
    } else if (strcmp(b->ingredients->name,i.name)!=0){
        b->numIng+=1;
        b->ingredients = (tIngredient*)realloc(b->ingredients, (b->numIng)*sizeof(tIngredient));
        strcpy (b->ingredients->name, i.name);
        b->ingredients->quantity = i.quantity;      
    } else {
        b->ingredients->quantity += i.quantity;
    }
   ```

   }

De esta forma, reservo memoria dinámica siempre y cuando el número de ingredientes sea 0, es decir, solo la primera vez, y las siguientes veces que llame a la función ya entrará en el else if puesto que ya será mayor de 0, por lo que uso realloc para que me mantenga la información anterior y me la amplíe en 1.

Comment: Se entiende que el campo `tIngredient *ingredients;` dentro de `tBurger` ha de ser un puntero **a un array** de ingredientes y no solo a un ingrediente. Cuando ese puntero es NULL es que no hay aún array, así que deberías crear uno con `malloc()` y darle el tamaño de un ingrediente. El acceso a un ingrediente particular sería con `b->ingredients[0]`, `b->ingredients[1]`, etc. Cada uno de esos sería ya un `struct` y no un puntero a struct, por lo que podrías hacer ` b->ingredients[0].name` por ejemplo. El realloc se haría sobre el puntero a array, para añadirle otro struct para otro ingrediente

Comment: Por otro lado, dentro del ingrediente, el nombre es un `char*`, es decir, otro puntero que debes inicializar antes de intentar copiar a él un nombre con `strcpy()`, o de lo contrario romperá. Puedes usar `strdup()` como alterativa a `malloc()+strcpy()`,  ya que `strdup()` te crea la memoria necesaria a la vez que copia la cadena, y te devuelve el puntero a la copia.

Comment: Entonces, según he entendido, debería hacer malloc según número de ingredientes (como en el primer momento b->numIng es 0, reservará solo 1 espacio de memoria) y luego ya ir ampliando con realloc? De esta forma:

Comment: void add_ingredient (tBurguer *b, tIngredient i){
 
 if (b->numIng==0){
  b->ingredients = (tIngredient*)malloc(b->numIng*sizeof(tIngredient));
 } else if (strcmp(b->ingredients->name,i.name)!=0){
         b->ingredients = (tIngredient*)realloc(b->ingredients, b->numIng*sizeof(tIngredient)); y ya abajo guardar los valores de las demás variables

Comment: Amigo, he hecho esto y se me ha arreglado. Muchísimas gracias!! Me has ayudado mucho. Un saludo!! :D

Comment: Veo en tu implementación que, si no entendí mal, añades un nuevo ingrediente cada vez que se invoca `add_ingredient()` si su nombre no coincide **con el del primer ingrediente**. Creí entender que el ingrediente se añade sólo si no estaba ya. Por tanto tendrías que recorrer el array de ingredientes para comparar con cada nombre, y sólo si no es igual a ninguno de ellos añadirlo. No estás usando sintaxis de array

Comment: Es cierto, pero ya lo arreglé luego. El problema que tenía era que no sabía en qué momento reservar la memoria con malloc para el primer ingrediente y pues el código no era el adecuado. Ya cuando pillé la idea con lo que me comentaste, lo ordené todo y ya funciona correctamente. Añade un ingrediente si no existe, y si existe solo incrementa la cantidad.

Comment: Quieres el código para tenerlo? Si te interesa, dímelo! :)

Comment: Quizás sea de interés para otros. ¿Por qué no escribes una respuesta? (que no sea méramente el código sino con alguna explicación para que sea más útil) Está permitido que te auto-respondas, podrías ganar puntos por ello. Incluso puedes marcar tu propia respuesta como aceptada.

Comment: Pues sí, estaría bien. Lo haré. Lo que no sé es cómo se marca la respuesta como solucionada o aceptada para que la gente vea que ya está resuelto.